# transform translateY doesn't work on Safari

Tags: html, css

It works great on Chrome on my desktop, but it just doesn't do the animation on Safari on my iPhone 8 (both on Safari and Chrome).

Any ideas?

```css
.voting-block {
    padding-top:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.voting-block2 {
    cursor:pointer;
    height: 77px;
    width: 74px;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    display:inline-block;
}

.voting-block2:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="voting-block">
  <img class="voting-block2" src="https://i.ibb.co/gZ73zPm/btn-haha.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/gugelm/pen/aeEJoX

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I just need to modify the body tag to this:
`<body ontouchstart="">`

iOS Safari doesn't trigger the :active pseudo-class unless a touch event is attached to the element.